# import a txt file with 2 columns into different columns in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a txt file containing numerous items in the following format

```
DBSERVER: HKSER
DBREPLICAID:  51376694590
DBPATH:  redirect.nsf
DBTITLE:  Redirect AP
DATETIME:  09.03.2015 09:44:21 AM
READS:  1
Adds:  0
Updates:  0
Deletes:  0

DBSERVER:  HKSER
DBREPLICAID:  21425584590
DBPATH:  redirect.nsf
DBTITLE:  Redirect AP
DATETIME:  08.03.2015 09:50:20 PM
READS:  2
Adds:  0
Updates:  0
Deletes:  0
.
.
.
.
```

[please see the source capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTNvG.png)

I would like to import the txt file into the following format in SQL

```
1st column  2nd column   3rd column     4th column    5th column  .....
DBSERVER    DBREPLICAID  DBPATH         DBTITLE       DATETIME    ......
HKSER       51376694590  redirect.nsf   Redirect AP   09.03.2015 09:44:21 AM
HKSER       21425584590  redirect.nsf   Redirect AP   08.03.2015 01:08:07 AM
```

[please see the output capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9s6z.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any chance you could export your data in wide format (columns, rather than rows)?  This would allow you to use the more standard SQL Server import wizard.

Comment: The file is in txt format and contains over 700 thousands rows of data. I tried to use excel to settle but in vain due to the huge amount of rows of data

Comment: I could fairly easily write a script in Java which can turn out the format you want.  But, are you willing to look outside of SQL Server for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can dump that file into a temporary table, with just a single text column. Once imported, you loop through that table using a cursor, storing into variables the content, and every 10 records inserting a new row to the real target table.

Not the most elegant solution, but it's simple and it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bulk insert you can insert these headers and data in two different columns and then using dynamic sql query, you can create a table and insert data as required.

Answer (score 0):

For Something like this I'd probably use SSIS.

The idea is to create a Script Component (As a Transformation)

You'll need to manually define your Output cols (Eg DBSERVER String (100))

The Src is your File (read Normally)

The Idea is that you build your rows line by line then add the full row to the Output Buffer.
Eg
Output0Buffer.AddRow();

Then write the rows to your Dest.

If all files have a common format then you can wrap the whole thiing in a for each loop